# Google Chrome Content script on secure https page. Permissions are right

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Sorry, found answer by myself (at the bottom of question)

I'm implementing simple google chrome addon (shows alert on android market, for now), and i'm facing with problems. What do i  have:

- Manifest (see below)
- Icon.png
- 2 JS files (jquery and mine)
- css file
- permissions seem to be ok

Contents of each:
Manifest:

```
{
    "name": "My first app",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description" : "My frist app",         
    "browser_action":
    {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "permissions":
    [
        "https://market.android.com/*"
    ],
    "content_scripts":
    [
        {
          "matches": ["https://market.android.com/*"],
          "css": ["styles.css"],
          "js": ["scripts.js", "jquery.js"]
        }
  ]
}
```

My css file:

```
*
{
    color:gray !important;
}
```

Scripts.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        alert("!");
});
```

Jquery version is **1.7.1**. 
And now comes the sugar:
All items on android market are **grayed**. But **no alert**.
Thank you in advance, Nick.

**OMG!**
Just needed jquery before my script running. Sorry.

Comment: add the answer ass and answer and mark it as solution so if anyone else has the same problem can see it easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to load jquery in your manifest before your script